# Running a sequence of methods

Tags: iphone

When I push a button I would like to run a sequence of methods   methodOne then methodTwo then methodThree.  When I run it now I only get the last method to run.  I would like them to run in order.  What am i doing wrong.

```
@implementation JackAnimationViewController
@synthesize color;



- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    [self methodOne];
    [self methodTwo];
    [self methodThree];
}

-(void) methodOne{
    color.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPressed.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPressed.png"],nil];      
    [color setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
    color.animationDuration = 1;
    [color startAnimating];}

-(void) methodTwo{
    color.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowPressed.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowPressed.png"],nil];      
    [color setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
    color.animationDuration = 1;
    [color startAnimating];}

-(void) methodThree{
    color.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPressed.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowDim.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPressed.png"],nil];      
    [color setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
    color.animationDuration = 1;
    [color startAnimating];}


@end
```

Comment: What type of class is `color`? Can you post the .h file?

Comment: @passedpawn based on the method names `color` looks like a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly setting the `animationImages` for the same `UIImageView` in each of those methods. Each time you do that it will replace the previous set and cancel that animation.

`startAnimating` is not synchronous, you will execute `methodTwo` immediately after `methodOne` and not when the animation defined in `methodOne` finishes.

To get the effect I believe you are looking for you could build a single larger array containing the images from all three animations in the order in which you want to cycle through them.
Alternately you could schedule `methodTwo` and `methodThree` to be invoked after the previous animations have finished but then you need to be prepared to cancel those calls if they are no longer needed or if you want to cancel the animation.

Comment: How do you schedule the methods

Comment: Take a look at the `NSTimer` class as well as the `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` methods on `NSObject`.